# How to stop "warnings" when using vim omni-completion with python?

Tags: python, vim

I am trying vim's python [omni-completion script](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1542), it works, but I got problem.

After I start vim, the 1st time I press  to ask vim to complete python code, many warning shown up.  That's because some python libs in my project use md5, which will trigger a warning message in python 2.6

That's very ignoring, how to stop vim/python from issuing warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a top level routine which imports the 3rd party library, you can insert this

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter("ignore",DeprecationWarning)
```

to ignore all deprecation warnings (which is what the `md5` warning is).

Check the `warnings` module for the details on more sophisticated filtering.

Comment: Yes!  It works!  But I didn't add it to my code, instead I changed the vim script for python omni-completion.